# Environmental variables in interactive and non-interactive shells

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, environment-variables

Say i am trying to execute a script userScript which has a line

```
env > ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES.txt
```

I do it in following two ways.

---

**1.**

By actually logging into it using ssh:

```
ssh host
password:xyz***
./userScript
```

ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES.txt does get created and contains result of the command env.

---

**2.**

```
ssh -i key host 'userScript'
```

ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.txt in this case does not get created.

Also, i believe the 1st case will be an example of interactive shell and the second is of non-interactive shell(Please correct me if i am wrong.). And there are differences in both mechanisms(whether files like .profile, .bashrc etc get executed or not).

How do i make sure that ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.txt get created in second case also? which environment variables to change for it?

Comment: Is it not getting created at all or is it not getting created where you expect it to be? What happens if you try a full path and/or print out the current directory in the script?

Comment: @EtanReisner Does not get created at all. This is a simplified snippet. BUt i am not making such naive mistake. Also, say if ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.txt already exists, it is unable to write to it.

Comment: What are the permissions of the file and its directory? What user are you ssh'ing into in each method?

Comment: @EtanReisner ssh -i Key host 'ls -l ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.txt' gives me -rw-r--r-- permissions and so does an ls -l while logged in via ssh. Also the user is the same in both the case and i am performing this operation in $USERS_HOME/scripts directory

Comment: Does running the script manually after using `ssh -i key host` work? Is there a forced command/etc. for that key perhaps?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes. Because that makes it an interactive shell login, just like a simple ssh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95260/discussion-between-user3814996-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: @user3814996 Please include the actual output of "ssh -v -i key host 'userScript'"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a different set of startup scripts is sourced for interactive and non-interactive sessions.

When you specify a command on an `ssh` command line, the non-interactive session is by default started.

To force the interactive session, use the `-t` switch. See the [`ssh` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> -t
>       Force pseudo-terminal allocation. ...

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't depend on the pseudo-terminal.  As I see it, the difference is in the specification of the command.  Use the full path, or relative from `$HOME` path on the `ssh` command line:

```
ssh -i key host '/add/path/here/userScript'
```

If there are problems with that, look at the output from `ssh`, and possibly run the command again with the `-v` option on ssh.

Also, be aware of your current directory, `ssh` usually starts in your home directory.  If your script is not in your home directory, then use the path as in the above example in this answer.

You can get a better answer quicker if you post the actual output from the commands that didn't create the file.

Comment: What if userScript was present in homedirectory itself?

Comment: You should prepend `./`, as in `./userScript`. Sorry I didn't make that more clear.  That's what I meant to say by "specification of command", poor wording on my part.  That's the difference you showed in your examples.  One had the `./` and the other didn't.  Yea, wow, as I reread my answer I see that I really didn't make the most obvious thing clear. Sorry!